# Add new object in list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list named StudentList. I want to add new object in list but want to use first item of list and update some some filed and then add it as new object in list.
But when I am doing so its updating the existing list only and not adding in list as new object.
Below is my code.
This is just a reference data. I have 50 fields in model and i need to use existing data and update one value and then need to add it as new object in list.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            // Student collection
            IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() {
        new Student() { StudentName = "John", Section ="A",Age = 13} ,
        new Student() { StudentName = "Moin",Section ="A",  Age = 21 } ,
        new Student() { StudentName = "Bill",Section ="A",  Age = 18 } ,
        new Student() {StudentName = "Ram" ,Section ="A", Age = 20} ,
        new Student() {StudentName = "Ron" ,Section ="A", Age = 15 }
    };

            

            var addnewStudent= studentList[0];
            addnewStudent.Age = 30;
            studentList.Add(addnewStudent);
             Console.WriteLine(studentList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you really using C# 4?

Comment: Have a look at using c# records if you're able to - they allow for the creation of a new (immutable) instance based on an select properties of an existing one

Comment: "I want to add new object in list" - that requires you to create a *new* object. `var addnewStudent= studentList[0];` doesn't create a new object... (It's not clear whether you understand what's currently happening and you're asking about a simple way to create a genuinely new object, or whether you're asking about why the code currently behaves the way it does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
var addnewStudent= studentList[0];
```

does not make a new copy of that student, it just makes a reference to the existing one.

If you want to make a new object, you must call `new Student()`. With that, you can then copy across all properties manually. Another option is if you are using C# 9 or newer is to use a `record` instead of a `class`. This gives you access to the `with` keyword that allows you to create a new object with identical properties while modifying only the ones you need. For example:

```
var addnewStudent = studentList[0] with
{ 
    Age = 30 
};
```

Comment: Using a record instead of a class is a hack if you don't use a record from the beginning(but a good tip anyway). In this case it's not the best way since OP's class `Student` has 50 properties and should remain a class.

Comment: Why would having 50 properties mean it should be a class?

Comment: well, i don't know where and how op is using it, so maybe this is even a valid use-case for a record even if it's unlikely with so many (not immutable) properties. But since OP is not really familiar with basic concepts of C#, it seems to me like a hack to tell him to avoid using classes because he wants to modify one property. The record has the copy builtin, but OP does not even know the difference between a class and a record.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Of course there is no rule: "if you exceed 10 properties, use a class instead of a struct/record". But the more properties your class has, the more likely it is that it should remain a class. Otherwise you should refactor it to not have so many properties. A record has [value eauality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#value-equality), so you are always comparing all 50 proprties whatever types they are, even if a `Student` had a `StudentId` property which would be enough.

Comment: "the more properties your class has, the more likely it is that it should remain a class" I completely disagree with that statement. Value equality is absolutely still useful regardless of how many properties you have.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to add new object in list but want to use first item of list
> and update some fields and then add it as new object to the list

You cannot add a *new* object without using `new`, if you update an existing object, you don't create a new one. So if you really want to take an existing object and modify one property, it might be a good idea to have a copy constructor. Here is a sample:

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Student(string studentName, string section, int age)
    {
        StudentName = studentName;
        Section = section;
        Age = age;
    }

    public Student(Student copyStudent) 
        : this(copyStudent.StudentName, copyStudent.Section, copyStudent.Age){}
}
```

The advantage is that you don't need to copy all properties where you want to create the new student from an existing but the class itself handles that:

```
var addnewStudent = new Student(studentList[0]);
addnewStudent.Age = 30;
studentList.Add(addnewStudent);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called *Shallow copy*. That is you copy the reference to the actual object. You need to create a *Deep copy* of your object to add it as a new object to your list.

You should try doing:

`var addnewStudent = new Student() { StudentName =  studentList[0].StudentName ,Section = studentList[0].Section, Age = 30 };`

then add it to your list.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you're making a reference to your first object and not create a new object try this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
       
    // Student collection
    IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() {
        new Student() { StudentName = "John", Section ="A",Age = 13} ,
        new Student() { StudentName = "Moin",Section ="A",  Age = 21 } ,
        new Student() { StudentName = "Bill",Section ="A",  Age = 18 } ,
        new Student() {StudentName = "Ram" ,Section ="A", Age = 20} ,
        new Student() {StudentName = "Ron" ,Section ="A", Age = 15 }
   };

   var addnewStudent=  new Student() { StudentName = "John", Section ="A",Age = 30} 
       
   studentList.Add(addnewStudent);
   Console.WriteLine(studentList);
}
```

Comment: This is just a reference data..I have a model of 50 fields and I need to update only one field in existing item and need to add it as new object. So do i need to write like this for all 50 fields.??

Comment: yeah,
look at this site : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Object_MemberwiseClone

looks like you can create a clone of you object as you first wanted

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Object.MemberwiseClone method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Object_MemberwiseClone).

The reason your code updates the list element is that your studentList is a list of **references** (as its elements are objects of class Student).

What you have to do is create a copy of the object. If Student class only has **value types** (int, char, string, double, etc), you coud simply add the new student by having a method (CreateCopy()) in it:

```
public Student CreateCopy()
{
   return (Student)this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

Now, if Student class has **reference type** fields (i.e. instances of classes), then you have to create a copy and assign a new instance to these fields. For example, let's suppose your Student class has a reference type field called "School":

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    private School _school;

    public Student(string studentName, string section, int age)
    {
         StudentName = studentName;
         Section = section;
         Age = age;
    }
    
    public Student CreateCopy()
    {
        Student otherStudent = (Student)this.MemberwiseClone();
        //Copy the instances of other classes that are fields
        //You could add a similar method to copy the school instance
        otherStudent.School = new School(_school.Name);
        return otherStudent;
    }
}
```

Then you can add the copy to the list by simply doing:

```
var addnewStudent= studentList[0].CreateCopy(); // Use CreateCopy()
addnewStudent.Age = 30;
studentList.Add(addnewStudent);
```

The advantage of this aproach is that if you only add **value types** fields to Student, the method CreateCopy() stays the same. If you use a copy-constructor as suggested in other answers, you gonna have to update it every time you add a new field to your class.

Not really about your question though, but you should consider using abstract classes to provide some *default* values to Student instead of always using the first element of the list.